exiftool-vendored structured tags
I am working on a project using exiftool-vendored (26.1.0), a JavaScript implementation of the ExifTool CLI.
For my use case, I want to provide fallback values for EXIF image tags if they are not defined on an image. This works well for many tag types, where if a tag hasn't been set in the returned Tags object, I can write a value to that tag key in a straightforward way: exiftool.write(absFilePath, { [tagName]: value }
However, some tags are part of structured data types accessible through a full tag definition or 'flattened' shorthand tag. Regardless of if you use the full tag definition or the 'flattened', there is an asymmetrical relationship between the userland key name specified, and the location of the data in the returned tag object.
For example, data written to the flattened Tag CreatorAddress is found under CreatorContactInfo.CiAdrCity, while the CreatorAddress is omitted from the returned object.
This appears to be different than the default handling of structured information by the CLI tool:

When reading, structures are flattened by default, and ExifTool returns one "flattened" tag for each field in the structure... (emphasis the authors)

From this, I was expecting the flattened tag to be included in the returned tags object from exiftool-vendored, but it isn't.
ie
import { exiftool } from 'exiftool-vendored'

exiftool.write(absFilePath, { ['CreatorAddress']: 'some address' }


const tags = await exiftool.read(filePath)

and a dump of tags would result in the following keys being set:

{
   ...
   // current behavior
   "CreatorContactInfo": {
      "CiAdrExtadr": "some address",
      ...
    },
   // But this flattened tag is *not* included
   "CreatorAddress": "some address",
   ...
}

What I've tried:
While we can't modify the behaviour of the provided exiftool instance, we can create a new instance by importing ExifTool and passing it options.
Reading the documentation for the ExifTool CLI, I am hopeful that some variation of the struct flag might provide a route to the behaviour Im looking for, but at the moment, none of the options seem to change the outcome.
export const exifExtract = new ExifTool({
  exiftoolArgs: ['-stay_open', 'True', '-@', '-', '-api', 'struct=2'] // 0,1,2, 
})

I've tried all the permutations but am not seeing the output change, so perhaps I'm passing it incorrectly or barking up the wrong tree. The fact that the output already deviates from the default CLI behaviour makes me doubt myself.
Any feedback from someone with experience on whether I'm going in the correct direction or have incorrect assumptions would be greatly appreciated.
After implementing @StarGeek's CLI corrections, the corrected flags are still not being implemented. What I've since uncovered is that exiftool-vendored has hard-coded the -struct flag into its .read() method, which cannot be overwritten by options set on a custom instance.
Ive raised this with the author as a ticket on the repo: https://github.com/photostructure/exiftool-vendored.js/issues/184

https://exiftool.org/struct.html#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20tags%20are%20copied,is%20disabled%3B%20see%20below.)
https://exiftool.org/ExifTool.html#Struct
https://exiftool.org/struct.html


@mrm, do you have the bandwidth to take a look at this?

You appear to be mixing up the -struct option, which has no arguments and cannot be set to anything, with the Perl exiftool Options function.  The -struct option is simply that. There are no other arguments or values to set for it. If you include it, then the data will be returned in a structured format, not as flattened tags. You would only set -struct=0 as part of Perl code, e.g. $exifTool->Options(Struct=>0);

@StarGeek - so are you saying its not possible to pass different -struct options via
exiftoolArgs ? exiftoolArgs takes an array of strings and has sparse documentation. The default is export const DefaultExiftoolArgs = ["-stay_open", "True", "-@", "-"]

@StarGeek For what its worth, it appears that the output of exiftool-vendored is already returning the equivalent of -struct being set, as I'm not seeing flattened tags being returned in the Tags object.

I have no knowledge about exiftool-vendored commands. I am saying that the -struct option is a flag option. Without including it would be the equivalent of struct=0 and including it would be struct=1. If you are getting structured data by default, you might check the default options on exiftool-vendored to see if its included. The final option you can try is to use the -api option to force the desired output. On the command line, it would be -api struct=0, but these would probably be separate entries with in the args array.

And if you want to see both structured data and flattened data when reading, you would use -api struct=2

@StarGeek thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've found the -struct flag baked into the .write() method, which is why even with your corrections, the output still wont include flatted tags. It's been raised as issue on the repo and I've updated the question above to reflect your comments.
https://github.com/photostructure/exiftool-vendored.js/issues/184

@StarGeek thanks for the assist! orionrush let's hammer out the solution on github.
